# python input UnicodeDecodeError:

Tags: python, unicode, input

python 3.x

```
>>> a = input()
hope
>>> a
'hope'
>>> b = input()
håpe
>>> b
'håpe'
>>> c = input()

start typing hå... delete using backspace... and change to hope

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 1: invalid continuation byte
>>>
```

The situation is not terrible, I am working around it, but find it strange that when deleting, the bytes get messed up. Has anyone else experienced this?

the terminal history shows that it thought that I entered `h?ope`

any ideas?

in the script that is using this, I do import `readline` to give command line history.

Comment: Sounds like a broken terminal, what terminal is it?

Comment: standard one, 6-7 year old macbook, 10.6.8, although I am running visor.

Comment: `readline` can [cause the Mac terminal to crash](https://github.com/ludwigschwardt/python-gnureadline/issues/54). On a second thought, the problem is that the Mac terminal can crash at all, so still a Mac problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like backspace is deleting the last *byte* instead of the last *character*. What ends up happening is that you type:

```
68 c3 a5
h |  å

68 c3 6f 70 65
h |  |o |p |e
```

In UTF-8, a byte with the first bit set (`c3`) means that the next byte must have its first bit set as well (see [Wikipedia's description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description)).

Make sure that your terminal emulator and readline understand you're using UTF-8.

Comment: this certainly makes sense. At least I know what is going on!

Comment: @beoliver The same problem happed to me. How to solve it? Thanks.

Comment: @mathsyouth As written in the answer: Set your terminal emulator, as well as readline itself, to UTF-8. In your terminal emulator, it's likely in the settings somewhere. readline will read the environment variables, namely `LC_ALL` and friends.