# How to use the input method for Japanese

Tags: python

```
message = input()
```

The line can accept user input for Japanese on my Mac. However, when the code runs on Ubuntu 18.04, it reports the following error:

```
    message = input()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 4-5: invalid continuation byte
```

How to make the encoding working on my Ubuntu? I searched and most posts are on file reading in UTF 8. How about the simple 'input()' function?

Comment: Just to make sure, you are on Python 3, right? Probably should add the tag since `input()` is notoriously different between 2 and 3.

Comment: Also, this might be a problem with the terminal. Related: [python input UnicodeDecodeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11386747/python-input-unicodedecodeerror)

Comment: @ImperishableNight. Yes, this is Python3. not 2