# Python input in unicode with backspace problem

Tags: python, linux, ssh, utf-8

My question is actually the question below:

[python input UnicodeDecodeError:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11386747/python-input-unicodedecodeerror)

in `s = input("Enter a name:")`, if the user enters a string in Unicode like علی and then press backspace and then enter (I mean using backspace to edit the input), it throws `UnicodeDecodeError`:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xdb in position 4: unexpected end of data
```

The accepted answer doesn't show any specific solution and relates it to the terminal and server encoding. I sat the `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` but it didn't solve the problem, the terminal also is in UTF-8. My PC OS is Ubuntu 20.04 and the server is ubuntu 16.04. The program is running on the server and I am connected to it via ssh.

it's the output of `locale` on the server:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

My python version on the server is 3.7.10. I tested this on my laptop with python 3.8.5, and hadn't a problem. Then I installed python 3.8.8 on server using conda, the problem persists.
Also this problem isn't in the Python console, but when I call "`python or python3.8 inp.py`", when the `input` command is in a file named `inp.py`.

Comment: you press backspace before 'enter'? 
for me it does not reproduce on Python 3.5.3 Windows 10

Comment: @Orb yes I hit backspace before enter. Can you write something unicode? like in a foreign script, ..

Comment: so that's what I did. on Windows it works. so it might be an OS compatibility issue. what Python version are you using (update your question). i know the input function changed from python 2 to python 3.

Comment: There are two consecutive _Zero Width Joiner_ characters in your question; couldn't this be a  culprit? Copy `like ‍‍علی and` and paste in Python prompt (between a pair of quotes); you get `'like \u200d\u200dعلی and'`.

Comment: Please mention the Python version you're using.

Comment: @Sumit `3.7.10`

Comment: @JosefZ sorry, I modified it, however in both cases (the old and new one), the problem is the same. If you probably copy and paste علی in front of `input` prompt and hit enter you may get the error.

Comment: Can you open an `xterm` on the server and reproduce there? If the error persists then the problem is server side and could be in the readline library. But if it solves it, then the problem is on the local system and you should ensure that UTF-8 is enabled there.